# Understanding JQuery smooth scroll failure

Tags: jquery

I'm new here so thanks in advance for your patience! I'm beginning learning JQuery and trying to understand how to implement a smooth scroll. I've searched for many tutorials and tried out this simple one so I could try to understand how the code works (and not rely on a plugin):

https://www.abeautifulsite.net/smoothly-scroll-to-an-element-without-a-jquery-plugin-2

I've set this up in codepen, but it doesn't work. The page just hops to the anchor points and doesn't scroll. I tried another (different) tutorial and got the same result. I'm obviously missing something basic but I can't figure it out, even after googling about and searching for answers. Can anyone help me out by explaining what's wrong?

https://codepen.io/dotdorothy/pen/BpRVZo

This is the code from the codepen JS section (the link above will show the HTML and CSS):

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {

var target = $(this.getAttribute('href'));

if( target.length ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 1000);
}

});
```

As I said, I'm new to coding so apologies if this seems like a really stupid question!

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yes, you need to include jQuery in your code pen

Comment: Ahhhaaa! I thought it was already added. I'm doing the Free Code Camp process and it kept saying "we've added this for you behind the scenes" during the tutorial tasks, so I didn't realise I'd missed the step. Thank you so much for your help!